# Force vs. impulse: what is the math description of their interaction?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors, work

[image]

In this image there are two forces acting on the same body, and we can decribe them mathematically and geometrically using vectors and the palallelogram rule.

NOw, suppose the box (stone, bullet..., $m =1$) is not moving upward because of a force, a lift, but has been shot and has $p = 20 kgm/s, v = 20m/s, KE = 200 J$

Gravity is doing negative work and subtracting energy:
$$F = -ma = 10 \cdot 1 = -10 N$$ 
 We cannot use the palallelogram here as KE is not a force, how do you deal with this situation, how do you describe it mathematically?

It is trivial that the box will reach the height KE/ F = 20 m and that there KE will be 0 and PE = 200, and at any height h $KE_h = 200 -PE_h$, but how do you describe the relation,  process, the action of negative work done on the body?

Answer (score 2):

If one takes the system in question to be the box, then gravity *does* take energy from it. The amount of work done by the earth (by gravity) is $W=F\Delta y = -mg\Delta y$.  Every time the box goes up a bit, the earth removes some energy.

As an example, let's calculate how much energy is removed by work when the box reaches its highest point and comes momentarily to rest ($v=0$).  Kinematics tells us how to calculate that height:  $$h=\frac{v_i^2}{2a} = \frac{v_i^2}{2g}$$
where $v_i$ is the initial speed with which the box was thrown.  The amount of work done by the earth (gravity) is $$W=F\Delta y = -mgh =-mg\frac{v_i^2}{2g} = -\frac{1}{2}mv_i^2$$
and we have the result that when the box reaches its highest point and comes momentarily to rest (and thus has zero kinetic energy) that the earth has done exactly the right amount of work to remove all of the box's initial kinetic energy.

Comment: I think this answer doesn't add anything additional to the answers already posted here.

Comment: FWIW, I posted this answer before the OP edited the question to include comments on potential energy.  This answer was intended to address the problem with the box as the system of interest (rather than the earth-box system), which was, at the time, what I thought the OP had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

You can NEVER subtract or add a force and an energy, or a force and a work. This is very important because their dimensions are different.
It would be like adding 3kg and 4m. What's the meaning of this ? None !

You need to understand that there is no real difference between a positive or a negative work. The only thing that changes is the sign.

In a force balance you don't consider KE. You consider KE in an energy balance. So if you want add things up, you need to write an energy balance in which there will be the KE, and the negative work from the weight. You can say that the variation of KE is equal to the work.

Comment: You should rephrase your question because you speak about "net resulting force", but it's obvious that if there is only one force applied....the resulting force consists in...this one force ! In a force balance you don't consider KE. You consider KE in an energy balance. So if you want add things up, you need to write an energy balance in which there will be the KE, and the negative work from the weight. You can say that the variation of KE is equal to the work.

Comment: What, in your mind, is different compared to the case where the work is positive ? It would be the same, except the two arrows would be pointing in the same direction. It's not because you can trace arrows that there are reasons to compare them.

Comment: @PierreAlvarez note that the question has been edited quite a bit, if you'd like to update your answer to match.

Comment: I still don't understand what part is specifically related to the negativity of the work. Let's say the box is moving downward because of KE directed downward and the gravity. Then the work would be positive, and it feels like in this case the author would know how to deal with it. I find it strange.